# "Through" or "From"?

Tags: word-choice

> Amy talks about her strong interest in finance developed through her internship in the trust fund.

I get confused about the word "through". Would it be appropriate to use it there?

Comment: *through* = by virtue of, by way of, by means of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context you provided *through* means *by means of, by way of, by dint of, via* and seems to be the correct usage. You could use *from* if you were referring to the internship more like a place or workspace.

Answer (score 1):

*Through* makes perfect sense there, and is probably the best choice.

Comment: @lessismore You don't need to say "Thank you" to every answer. The SE way to say thank you is to upvote, and eventually to accept the most suitable answer.

Comment: The OP might find it helpful if the down-voter would say why _through_ might not be suitable.